# How to make an agglomerative clustering plot in sci-kit learn with an input list of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I try the following code, where X is an input list of array:

```
colors = ["#f7bd01", "#377eb8", "#f781bf"]
model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=3, linkage="average")
model.fit(X)
plt.figure()
plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
for l, color in zip(np.arange(model.n_clusters), colors):
    plt.plot(X[model.labels_ == l].T, c=color, alpha=0.5)
plt.axis("tight")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

However, this code produces TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
What's wrong with it?

P.S. This is what X looks like:

```
[array([31.13325031, 28.64259029, 27.39726027, 24.90660025, 24.28393524,
        26.15193026, 26.15193026, 24.90660025, 26.77459527, 23.66127024,
        23.66127024, 21.17061021, 23.03860523, 19.30261519, 18.67995019,
        18.67995019, 19.30261519, 19.30261519, 18.67995019, 19.30261519,
        18.05728518, 18.05728518, 17.43462017, 16.81195517, 17.43462017,
        17.43462017, 17.43462017, 17.43462017, 18.67995019, 21.17061021,
        19.30261519, 20.54794521, 19.9252802 , 21.17061021, 20.54794521,
        21.79327522, 24.90660025, 31.13325031, 23.66127024, 19.30261519,
        21.79327522, 20.54794521, 13.69863014, 16.81195517, 15.56662516,
        18.05728518, 18.05728518, 16.81195517, 19.9252802 , 16.81195517,
        18.05728518, 20.54794521, 16.81195517, 18.67995019, 21.17061021,
        19.9252802 , 16.81195517, 16.18929016, 17.43462017, 18.05728518,
        18.67995019, 15.56662516, 18.05728518, 19.30261519, 18.05728518,
        15.56662516, 17.43462017, 18.05728518, 16.18929016, 19.9252802 ,
        26.77459527, 28.01992528, 29.26525529, 33.00124533, 33.62391034,
        34.86924035, 36.73723537, 34.86924035, 31.75591532, 34.24657534,
        35.49190535, 33.62391034, 31.75591532, 24.90660025, 26.77459527,
        29.26525529, 31.13325031, 28.01992528, 26.77459527, 26.77459527,
        24.90660025, 26.15193026, 27.39726027, 26.77459527, 23.66127024,
        24.28393524]),
 array([22.41594022, 22.41594022, 20.54794521, 20.54794521, 22.41594022,
        21.79327522, 19.9252802 , 23.03860523, 20.54794521, 21.17061021,
        21.79327522, 21.79327522, 19.30261519, 18.67995019, 19.30261519,
        19.9252802 , 18.67995019, 18.05728518, 19.30261519, 18.67995019,
        17.43462017, 16.18929016, 16.18929016, 15.56662516, 15.56662516,
        15.56662516, 14.94396015, 17.43462017, 19.30261519, 22.41594022,
        19.9252802 , 23.66127024, 26.15193026, 32.37858032, 42.34122042,
        37.98256538, 37.98256538, 38.60523039, 41.09589041, 41.71855542,
        37.35990037, 37.98256538, 38.60523039, 39.8505604 , 44.83188045,
        47.94520548, 42.96388543, 36.73723537, 24.90660025, 18.05728518,
        19.30261519, 21.79327522, 18.05728518, 22.41594022, 40.4732254 ,
        36.73723537, 34.86924035, 34.24657534, 35.49190535, 31.13325031,
        34.24657534, 34.24657534, 34.86924035, 39.22789539, 40.4732254 ,
        34.86924035, 37.98256538, 36.11457036, 39.22789539, 44.20921544,
        49.19053549, 52.30386052, 51.05853051, 51.05853051, 54.79452055,
        57.28518057, 47.32254047, 33.62391034, 34.86924035, 40.4732254 ,
        38.60523039, 36.11457036, 31.75591532, 31.13325031, 29.26525529,
        28.01992528, 29.26525529, 28.64259029, 26.77459527, 28.64259029,
        26.77459527, 24.90660025, 23.03860523, 23.03860523, 23.66127024,
        24.28393524]),......
```

Comment: X.shape? how many dimension?

Comment: The shape is (725, 96)